# Connecting Linux Mint 16 to Wifi

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

I saw the previous answers to a very similar question that seemed to be solved for the requestor. The answers assumed that one can have a "hardwire" connection to the internet. Terdon said something about dropping a line to him if the assumption was not correct. I have that problem. I don't have any access to a cable connection. I do have the original Linux Mint 16 CD though. Is that any help? Will it contain the b43 firmware installer that was referred to in the previous answers?

Comment: Sorry for the bother. I actually found a nearby place where I could plug in a cable and do what was suggested in a previous post. It has worked out for me. Thanks.